# DEB Equivalent for RPM's 'replace' utility

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, text-processing

I often use the very handy `replace` command on my CentOS server:

> The replace utility program changes strings in place in files or on the standard input.

It's not a standalone package even on the RPM side, I think it's part of a larger utility package. Anyway, I'm wondering if there's an Ubuntu equivalent of this? I know I can faff around with `grep` and `sed`, but `replace` is much more convenient.

Comment: Can you [edit] and provide an example how it’s used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mariadb-server-10.1`, `mysql-server-5.7` and `percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7` packages contain versions of `replace`, but these versions seem to be mostly old and some are even deprecated.

The software has a website called https://replace.richardlloyd.org.uk, unfortunately the download link there is broken, but you can download the latest version (2.24 currently) as a `.tar.gz` file from [here](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Users/replace-2.24/): Scroll all the way down and select “HTTP” on the last line. Follow these steps to install `replace` from this file:

1. Extract the `.tar.gz` archive:

   ```
   tar xf replace-*.tar.gz
   ```
2. Change into the directory:

   ```
   cd replace-*/
   ```
3. The installation needs `gmake`, but it’s called `make` in Ubuntu, so create a symlink:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/make /usr/bin/gmake
   ```
4. Run `gmake`:

   ```
   gmake
   ```
5. Change the shebang of `tests/runtests` to `bash` (because it uses `let`, which `sh` doesn’t have):

   ```bsh
   sed '1s/sh/bash/' tests/runtests
   ```
6. Run the tests:

   ```
   gmake test
   ```
7. Install the software to `/usr/local/bin/replace`:

   ```
   sudo gmake install
   ```

Once it’s installed you can remove the `/usr/bin/gmake` symlink as well as the `replace-N.NN/` directory and the `.tar.gz` file:

```
cd .. && rm -r replace-*/ replace-*.tar.gz && sudo rm /usr/bin/gmake
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll get this one rather than insall the entire mysql-server package.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on but the download on that site seems to be some kind of weird .depot package. After some head-scratching I gave up and went with the other answer to extract from mariadb-server although it's version 1.4

Comment: @JimDeadlock Wow, the website’s download link is broken – I changed the answer and provided instructions to get the correct file.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't spot the one at the bottom, I was messing around with those other binary files and getting all confused haha! I now have 2.24 working like a charm, awesome!

Comment: I used make and it worked fine btw.

Answer (score 5):

This is an alternative way for `replace 2.24` which is not from source using `alien` to install the rpm file since this is an app that is already part of Red Hat / CentOS.

Feel free to copy and paste the following lines in a terminal window.

```
cd /tmp
sudo apt install alien
wget https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/RPMS/replace2-2.24-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo alien replace2-2.24-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo dpkg -i replace2_2.24-2_amd64.deb
```

Then run the new app

```
$ replace2 
replace 2.24 (C) Richard K. Lloyd 2004 - The sane person's alternative to sed

Syntax: replace2 [-?] [-A] [-b] [-c startcol] [-d tempdir] [-e] [-f]
                 [-h] [-i] [-L] [-l linenum] [-m maxreplines] [-n] [-P] [-p]
                 [-r|R] [-s] [-T] [-t maxtimes] [-u backupsuffix] [-v]
                 [-w] [-x suffix [-x...]] [-z]
                 old_str new_str [-a old_str new_str...] [filename...]

-? displays this syntax message.
-A forces the program to assume all files are text files. Normally, the first
   256 bytes are examined to auto-determine if a file is text or binary.
   This option is deprecated and may be changed or removed in a future release.
-a allows extra pairs of strings to be replaced in order.
-b forces the program to assume all files are binary files.
-c startcol starts the string replace from column 'startcol' rather than the
   first column.
-d specifies the temporary directory for storing modified files. If not
   supplied, the default directory is $TMPDIR or, if that isn't set, /tmp.
-e makes search case-sensitive. new_str exactly replaces old_str
   with no case-adjustment to new_str.
-f forces the update of files without any .cln backup.
-h indicates that replacement pairs are binary hex data.
-i interactively prompts the user to confirm if they want strings replaced in
   next file. Specifying -i -i switches to prompting for each replacement.
-L follows soft-links specified on the command line.
-l linenum starts the string replacement from line 'linenum' rather than the
   first line.
-m maxreplines specifies the maximum number of lines in a file that should
   have string replacements.
-n displays what strings would be replaced without actually replacing them.
   It also switches on verbose mode.
-P pre-pads new_str with leading spaces if it is shorter than old_str.
-p pads new_str with trailing spaces if it is shorter than old_str.
-r or -R recurses down the current directory tree (if no filenames are given),
   replacing strings in all files found. Use -x to narrow the recursion.
-s relaxes the condition that old_str has to match a 'word' i.e. it replaces
   old_str even if it is a substring of a 'word'.
-T retains the timestamps of the original unmodified files.
-t maxtimes states the maximum number of times a string can be replaced
   in any single line of a file.
-u backupsuffix specifies the backup suffix for the unmodified file.
-v increments (switches on) verbose mode, reporting a summary of replacements
   if specified once and all replacements if specified twice (i.e. -vv).
-w recursively replaces strings in all Web-related source files in the current
   directory tree. Equivalent to "-r -x .html -x .htm -x .asp -x .js -x .css
   -x .xml -x .xhtml -x .shtml -x .jsp -x .php -x .php3 -x .php4 -x .pl".
-x suffix specifies a case-insensitive filename suffix to look for when
   recursing. Multiple -x params can be supplied and have an "or" meaning.
-z Zero-terminate any binary replacement string.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that is indeed the one I'm looking for, thanks. I know it's on its last legs but I'm enjoying it while I can :)

Comment: @JimDeadlock Let me rewrite something here where you can extract it from a different application that doesn't scream deprecated.  By the way, this answer only installs replace.  You can delete the .deb file that gets downloaded when complete.

Comment: 1.4 works just fine for me, but 2.24 would be welcome.

Comment: @JimDeadlock I would love to come up with something for you.  It will take me a bit to find it.  :)

Comment: @JimDeadlock Updated for 2.24.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, useful to know about extracting things from other packages. However, I think dessert's download link for the original app is more straightforward.

Comment: @JimDeadlock No worries.  This is just an alternative way of no need to build from source.